# Pymongo find by _id field

Tags: python, mongodb, flask

Estoy intentando consultar mi base de datos de Mongo para encontrar un valor por el campo "_id" con el valor que devuelve la función url_for() desde el template. Aunque he comprobado que el valor que aparece en la URL y el que pasa al router es correcto, la base de datos no devuelve ninguna coincidendia.

Aquí está el código del router:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask import render_template
import pymongo
from pymongo import MongoClient
import re
from bson.objectid import ObjectId

try:
    dbClient = MongoClient().fabrica.fichas
    print("successful connection to fichas")
except:
    print('An error occurred on line {} in statement {}'.format(line, text))
    exit(1)

app=Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/ficha/<id>')
def ficha(id):
    id=ObjectId(id)
    print(id)
    return render_template('ficha.html', ficha_data=dbClient.find({"_id":ObjectId(id)}))
```

Y este es el código del template:

```
<!doctype html>
<title>Hello from Flask</title>
  <h2>Fichas</h2>
  <style>th{text-align: left; width: 15%;}</style>
  <table id="navigation">
        <tr>
            <th>Ref</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Leather</th>
            <th>Color</th>
            <th>Client</th>
        </tr>
    {% for ficha in datos %}
        <tr>
            <td><a href="{{ url_for('.ficha', id=ficha['_id'])}}">{{ficha['ref']}}</a></td>
            <td>{{ficha['name']}}</td>  
            <td>{{ficha['leather']}}</td> 
            <td>{{ficha['color']}}</td>
            <td><a href="{{ url_for('.fichas_cliente', cliente=ficha['client']) }}">{{ficha['client']}}</a></td>
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}
  </table>
```

¡Muchas gracias!

Comment: estas en stackoverflow español... podrias traducirlo del ingles al español para poder ayudarte con tu pregunta.. gracias..!!

Comment: Ups, perdón, creí haberlo colgado en la página en inglés. Lo traduzco. Gracias

Comment: porque no usas esto: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.with_entities

Comment: No entiendo tu respuesta @Tegito123, ¿que tiene que ver sql con Mongo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

tu query es esta:

```
dbClient.find({"_id":ObjectId(id)})
```

el campo _id es un campo de identificación primaria (generado automáticamente por MongoDB) y a su vez es cierto que se comporta como un "ObjectId", pero también puedes hacer consultas a ese mismo campo con el valor cuando es un string. Ejemplo _id : 3828d2u3er2038eu238du

Yo creo que la consulta correcta debería ser esta:

```
dbClient.find_one({"_id": id )})
```

recuerda que "_id" al ser un identificador primario no se puede repetir en la colección y por eso uso el **find_one** para la query.

Comment: Gracias Enrique, al final el problema era que la consulta devolvía un iterador, lo he solucionado así:

     fichas=dbClient.fichas.find({"_id":ObjectId(id)})[0]

Un saludo

Comment: Por buena practica si solo buscas un registro deberías usar la herramienta adecuada que en este caso seria el find_one. hace algún tiempo también trabajaba así como tu hasta que empece a tener problemas en el rendimiento de mis algoritmos.